# Power BI Slicer customization

Tags: powerbi

I have scenario to show the column names as dropdown values in the slicer. There are 4 fields plus 'All' should appear in the slicer dropdown. Those fields are flag fields. Whenever the value is selected in the slicer, the report page should filter the visualizations only to 'True' of that particular selected field.

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What's your measure code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you expecting the ability to select more than one option in the slider e.g. picking FlagField1 and FlagField2 gives only rows that have both set?

Comment: @BarneyL - The slicer is only 'single select' option. When FlagField1 is selected in the slicer, then other visuals like pie chart in the Report page should be filtered internally with database column 'FlagField1'  = TRUE. When nothing is selected in the slicer, the report page would reset the filters and show the data related to TRUE and FALSE of the flag columns.

Comment: @Olly - I am new to Power BI. I have tried creating a Measure with SELECTEDVALUE to identify which flagfield column is selected in the slicer. But the Measure is incomplete as I am not able to proceed further. **Calc = IF([Selected Scope] = "FlagField1",[FlagField1] = TRUE(),FALSE())**

Comment: @Kavi I think you're misunderstanding how the data should be structured. If each of those flags are separate columns rather than values within one column then I would expect there to be a slicer for each because you might encounter meaningful combinations. What happens when flag 1 and flag 2 are both true for example? Your approach at present will require either special handling in every measure you create or require a many to many relationship via a bridge table.

Comment: @BarneyL - Thanks! The same implementation is already done in Tableau using Parameter. Now as we migrate from Tableau to Power BI, we got to do this in Power BI. With regards to your point, it will never be a multi select slicer, so there wont be any problem of having mutliple TRUE scenario.

Comment: @Kavi I think you have two options. Which one is best will depend on how many measures you need in your reports and how much re-use you'll get out of the model. The quick solution is to create four measures using CALCULATE to filter the results based on each of the flags and then a final measure using SWITCH to choose between them based on the slicer. The downside to this is if you need a lot of measures then the work involved escalates quickly. If you're building for a lot of measures or long term use then you're looking at a bridge table and a many to many relationship.